# Getting Error in Send Grid Configuration [ unexpected '[', expecting ')' in E:\xampp\htdocs\sendgrid-php\lib\helpers\mail\Mail.php on line 37]

Tags: php, sendgrid

While running a code to auto-send an email through Sendgrid APIss, we are getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in E:\xampp\htdocs\sendgrid-php\lib\helpers\mail\Mail.php on line 37

Below is the mail.php file code:

```
public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_filter(
            [
                'email' => $this->getEmail()
            ],
            function ($value) {
                return $value !== `enter code here`null;
            }
        ) ?: null;
    }
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Upgrade........

Comment: i am using php 5.3.8.